# GAE image feature not working despite successful PIL installation

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-imaging-library

I followed the PIL installation at http://nyteshade.posterous.com/macos-x-107x-python-27-and-pil and I believed I have successfully installed it. (Typing "import Image" at the python console doesn't give me an error.) However, I am still encountering the following error in using google-app-engine's image.resize():

NotImplementedError: Unable to find the Python PIL library.  Please view the SDK documentation for details about installing PIL on your system.

Now I'm not sure if the installation was successful or if there's anything I missed out during the installation. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try these docs instead: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/installingPIL